# is there is a way to limit the number of images which user select them from imagePicker.pickMultiImage()?

Tags: flutter, imagepicker

I am working on a restaurant reservations project.
I have two apps,
One for the user and another for the manager.
The manager can upload photos of his restaurant. I  don’t want it to select over 3 photos.
In the ImagePicker library in method pickMultiImage(), I cannot determine the maximum number of images allowed to be selected.
Is there a way to limit the number of photos that can be selected?

final ImagePicker _picker = ImagePicker();

final List? images = await _picker.pickMultiImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);

Comment: Hi, not sure if the functionality exists, but I eard about `imagePickerController.imageLimit = 5`. Let me know if it works :)

Comment: Have you got the solution as i am also stuck on the same.

Comment: did you find a solution? I cant find anything and there is nothing on docs...

Answer (score 2):

After picking images, use take() this method returns iterable starting from index 0 till the count provided from the given list. here is you have a list with using toList()

var myList = [0, 'one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five'];

myList.take(3).toList()  // [0, one, two]

Copied from here
https://stackoverflow.com/a/67208482/13758642